# Link one row of table to multiple rows in another table in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this form:

[image: Form Image]

After submitting the form, personal details will be inserted into personal table and book details into book table. I would like to link one personal table row to multiple rows in the book table (since it is inserting with same query) through a unique id, so I can identify that these books are related to this person at a later time.

This is my PHP and MySQL script:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database);

$users_firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$users_middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
$users_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$users_gender= $_POST['gender'];
$users_location= $_POST['location'];
$users_email= $_POST['email'];
$users_mobile= $_POST['mobile'];

$query = "INSERT INTO personaldetails(FirstName ,MiddleName,LastName,
Gender,Location,Email,Mobile) VALUES ('$users_firstname',
'$users_middlename', '$users_lastname', '$users_gender','$users_location','$users_email','$users_mobile');";

foreach($_POST['booktitle'] as $key => $bookTitle) {
    $bookTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $bookTitle);
    $bookGenre = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['bookgenre'][$key]);
    $bookWriter = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['bookwriter'][$key]);
    $bookDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['bookdescription'][$key]);

    $query .= "INSERT INTO bookdetails(BookTitle ,BookGenre,BookWriter,
                BookDescription) VALUES('$bookTitle',
             '$bookGenre', '$bookWriter', '$bookDescription');";
}

$result = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One posssible solution is by using [mysqli_insert_id](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp).

But you will also have to create an extra column in **book table** for storing user's id to relate a book with a user, let it be **user_id**(which will store the id of newly created user that we will get by `mysqli_insert_id()` )

and you will also have to execute the queries seperately to get the newly inserted user's Id.

So the code will be like -

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$database);

    $users_firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $users_middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
    $users_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $users_gender= $_POST['gender'];
    $users_location= $_POST['location'];
    $users_email= $_POST['email'];
    $users_mobile= $_POST['mobile'];

    $user_query = "INSERT INTO personaldetails(FirstName ,MiddleName,LastName,
    Gender,Location,Email,Mobile) VALUES ('$users_firstname',
    '$users_middlename', '$users_lastname', '$users_gender','$users_location','$users_email','$users_mobile');";

//execute the user query
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $user_query);
//get the user id of newly inserted user
$user_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

    foreach($_POST['booktitle'] as $key => $bookTitle) {
        $bookTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $bookTitle);
        $bookGenre = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['bookgenre'][$key]);
        $bookWriter = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['bookwriter'][$key]);
        $bookDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['bookdescription'][$key]);

//use the user id here to relate it with the book
    $book_query = "INSERT INTO bookdetails(BookTitle ,BookGenre,BookWriter,
                BookDescription, user_id) VALUES('$bookTitle',
             '$bookGenre', '$bookWriter', '$bookDescription', '$user_id');";
//execute the query for book
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $book_query);

}
```

Comment: showing this error,

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Comment: Thank you so much @manoj :) though it is not unique but i have basic idea now  i will do it .  thanks a lot